# Logical flaw: if List<String> is null return input else print function output

Tags: java, null, wordnet, stemming, data-processing

In my code I call this method, as a preprocessing step to 'stem' words:

```
public void getStem(String word)
{
    WordnetStemmer stem =  new WordnetStemmer( dict );

    List<String> stemmed_words = stem.findStems(word,  POS.VERB);
    System.out.println( stemmed_words.get(0) );
}
```

Usually everything is good if it gets a normal word (I'm using the Java Wordnet Interface to handle the stemming). The thing is--> I don't always get a normal word, somethings I get things along the lines of `isa` which is a conjunction of `is` and `a`. In such a case that method will return `null` and my program will crash. How can I defend against this?

This is how I call that code:

```
public Sentence(String verb, String object, String subject ) throws IOException
{
    WordNet wordnet = new WordNet();

    this.verb = verb;
    this.object = object;
    this.subject = subject;

    wordnet.getStem( verb );
}
```

Eventually I want that to read:

```
this.verb = wordnet.getStem( verb );
```

I once heard about doing something with null objects, is that applicable here?

I tried this but it didn't work, but **I want to do something like this**:

```
public void getStem(String word)
{
 WordnetStemmer stem =  new WordnetStemmer( dict );

 List<String> stemmed_words = stem.findStems(word,  POS.VERB);
 if( stemmed_words != null)
     System.out.println( stemmed_words.get(0) );
 else
     System.out.println( word );
}
```

This is the output:

```
prevent
contain
contain
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
at java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:4454)
at inference_learner.WordNet.getStem(WordNet.java:76)
at inference_learner.Sentence.<init>(Sentence.java:23)
at inference_learner.RegEx.match_regex_patterns(RegEx.java:33)
at inference_learner.ReadFile.readFile(ReadFile.java:30)
at inference_learner.Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

Comment: what object is null? If `stemmed_words` is null, then the above way is correct.  Are you facing some other problem?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I don't know, I just posted the error message

Comment: Where did you get the idea that something is null?

Comment: i think because in the debugger things are initialized to null so i figured it would still be null if nothing was put there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because the `List` is not `null`, the `List` is empty.
You have to do the check like this `if (stemmed_words.size() > 0)`

Comment: Omnes Titus grando magna!

Comment: @Yamada_Tarō you should actually use if (stemmed_words.isEmpty()) 
By the way, stemmed_words does not conform to standard Java naming, you should use stemmedWords

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if( stemmed_words != null && stemmed_words.size() > 0))
     System.out.println( stemmed_words.get(0) );
 else
     System.out.println( word );
}
```

Comment: top ranked. thank you. i think @Titus is right though, it's going to be empty and not null